# Get a checkbox value in a different column

Tags: jquery

What I want to do from the following html is I would like to see if the checkbox 1 is checked or not when I click checkbox 2.

If the checkbox 1 is not checked, I get `alert` message. Otherwise, the checkbox 
2 can be checked.

```js
$('#table1').on('click',function(){
  //code...
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="check" value="1"/><label>1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="check" value="2"/><label>2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="check" value="1"/><label>3</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="check" value="2"/><label>4</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have no ideas with jQuery because I am a new learner. Please help me.

Comment: As you want that checkbox 2 can't be checked when checkbox 1 is checked, it would be the easiest way to just disable checkbox 2 when checkbox 1 is checked.

Comment: @matthias_h When checkbox 1 is checked, the checkbox 2 can be checked. Otherwise, the checkbox can't be checked. Then I have to check the checkbox 1 to check the checkbox2,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$("#2").click(function() {
   if ($("#1").prop("checked") == false ) {
     alert("checkbox 1 is not checked");
     $("#2").prop("checked", false);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="check" value="1" /><label>1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="check" value="2" /><label>2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you also want to uncheck checkbox 2 when checkbox 1 gets unchecked, you could do it like this:

```js
$("#2").click(function() {
  if ($("#1").prop("checked") == false ) {
    alert("checkbox 1 is not checked");
    $("#2").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
$("#1").click(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
   $("#2").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table id="table1" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="check" value="1" /><label>1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="check" value="2" /><label>2</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Update: The question was edited to now have 2 rows with 4 checkboxes.

```js
$("#2, #4").click(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().prev().find("input").prop("checked") == false) {
    let checkbox = $(this).parent().prev().find("input").attr("id");
    alert("checkbox " + checkbox + " is not checked");
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
  }
});
$("#1, #3").click(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
    $(this).parent().next().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="check" value="1" /><label>1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="check" value="2" /><label>2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="check" value="1" /><label>1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="check" value="2" /><label>2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps. What if there are more than two rows? How can I see if each the checkbox 1 is checked or not?

Comment: @Glad that I was able to help. I noticed you updated your question which now has 4 checkboxes instead of 2 and that you use both of the ids a second time for the new checkboxes. This is not allowed in HTML as ids have to be unique. Better use classes instead. Is checkbox 4 also dependent on checkbox 1 or is it just depending on the state of checkbox 3 like checkbox 2 is depending on checkbox 1?

Comment: My bad! I edited. You are right. The checkbox 4 like the checkbox 2 can or can't be checked depending the the checkbox 3, like the checkbox 1. In this case, do I iterate the checkbox? I didn't change the value on purpose

Comment: @hhhello I just updated my answer with a solution for this setting. 2 depending on 1 and 4 depending on 3.

Comment: @hhhello My bad, I thought you would use the same classnames 1 and 2 for checkboxes 3 and 4. It's easier if you can adjust the classnames like I have them in my example, otherwise I would have to adjust my code to work with 4 different classnames.

Comment: I have my own class. Those four have the same class name. That is why I classified them into id. In your example, if I want to use id, instead of class, what do I have to change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212817/discussion-between-matthias-h-and-hhhello).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```js
$('#2').change(function() {
  let checked = 0;
  $('#1').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      checked += 1;
    }
  });
  if (checked != 0) {

  } else {
alert("1 is not checked");
document.getElementById("2").checked = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="check" value="1"/><label>1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="check" value="2"/><label>2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do as you requested and will showcase every scenario might occure

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="check" value="1"/><label>1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="check" value="2" disabled="disabled"/><label>2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#table1 input', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 1) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert('checkbox 1 is now checked');
                $('#2').removeAttr('disabled');
            }else {
                alert('checkbox 1 is now not checked');
                $('#2').prop('checked', false);
                $('#2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert('checkbox 2 is now checked');
            }else {
                alert('checkbox 2 is now not checked');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```